# Time always like E+12 (floating point number) on server

Tags: php, api, post, time, timestamp

I'm having the problem that when I output `time()*1000` on my server I get result equal to **1.428653092E+12**. Locally I get a result like this: **1428653334000**.

Now when I want to POST it with curl to an API (Bullhorn API) I get an error that the data type is not correct (should be timestamp). This only happens on the server and not locally. So this has to do with the notation of my date field that I try to save ... .

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check the value of the php.ini [precision](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) setting on the server and your localhost

Answer (score 0):

you can remove  scientific notation by using

sprintf:

```
<?php 

    $value = time()*1000;
    echo $test = sprintf('%f',$value); // this will return in float data always

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why OP's integers are displayed in scientific notation